# Development of a custom module with TS in React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, package, npm-link

I have 2 projects with common functionality.

I need to develop my own npm module that will use common code snippets for this.

I made a separate project that will contain this shared code (eg util).

At the moment I have done the following:
we have 3 projects: **project-a**, **project-b**, **front-components**

I'm posting a "**front-components**" project in our company's npm.
Then I just include it in the rest of the projects as dependencies in the *package.json*

To develop this module locally, I do the following:

1. I copy the **node_modules** folder from the desired project to "**front-components**"

   ln -s ../project-a/node_modules ./node_modules
2. Making an npm link from **project-a**

   npm link ../front-components
3. Developing

But now I am facing difficulty in configuring *tsconfig.json*

For example, in "**front-components**" there is such code:

```
import { DATE_FORMAT } from 'constants/date';
```

And I get an error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'constants/date' in '..../front-components/src/hooks'
```

I think that the problem is in *tsconfig.json*, but I can't figure out why it occurs.

**Question 1**: Can I use some other approach to avoid copying node_modules into "**front-components**"? (I need the files to be in .ts and .tsx format, not d.ts)

**Question 2**: How can I solve the problem with imports?

**P.S.**: Maybe you have some advice on how to develop this kind of bundles, I will be grateful

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6", // Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'.
    "module": "esnext", // Specify library files to be included in the compilation.
    "lib": [
      // Specify library files to be included in the compilation.
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true, // Allow javascript files to be compiled
    "jsx": "react-jsx", // Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.
    "noEmit": true, // Do not emit outputs.
    "isolatedModules": true, // Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule').

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true, // Enable all strict type-checking options.

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, // Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement.
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true, // Include 'undefined' in index signature results.

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node", // Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6).
    "baseUrl": "src", // Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names.
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'.
    "esModuleInterop": true, // Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'.

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Skip type checking of declaration files.
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, // Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file.

    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "./global.d.ts"],
  "files": ["node_modules/front-components/src/index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As both your projects depends on same UI components it sounds like what you need is [monorepo](https://monorepo.tools/). It gives you a flexibility in dependency management in a way you need (current approach seems to be overcomplicated and not so efficient). Depending on package manager you use you can choose the approach for it. Here's a yarn workspaces based [example](https://github.com/TomFern/semaphore-demo-monorepo-typescript). I do not mean you have to switch to yarn berry, it's just one very minimalistic example that gives you a breath idea of monorepo. My personal preference is [Nx](https://nx.dev/), so google for more info and good luck, enjoy coding!